# Kendo-grid hide row (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Does the kendo-grid (Angular 2) provide a way to hide specific rows. (e.g. `[rowClass]="rowCallback"`). I would like to check a certain bool property of the binding item and based on the value show or hide the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straight-forward approach would be to either filter the data before hand, or provide an initial filter descriptor for the Grid, e.g.:

[Preprocess the data example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3gtz3?file=app/app.component.ts)

[Provide an initial filter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gz4ngz?file=app/app.component.ts)

You can also use the rowClass callback to add a custom class to the respective grid rows based on some data item property (available as args.dataItem):

[Hide via RowClass](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3gtz3-zegy1k?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: How can I hide both master row and its detail using RowClass?

Comment: Adding a custom class to the rows that need to be hidden will allow for selecting their respective detail rows, and hide them via CSS, e.g.:

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjv2gp?file=app/app.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjv2gp?file=app/app.component.ts)